# Why does a while loop and a for loop only return me the information of the last iteration?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

Here I am playing around with the coin gecko api. I am trying to log the price of bitcoin while 10 is not equal to 0, so basically 10 times. It works fine, only the iteration doesn't show accordingly. Instead it just shows the last iteration instead of every time it actually iterates.

**seems as though iteration doesn't log accordingly inside the axios call but when I do console.log(iteration) just above it, It works fine.

```
    const [coinData, setCoinData] = useState([]) 

    iteration = 10
    while (iteration != 1) {

  
        axios.get(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/history?date=11-04-2022`).then((res) => {

                console.log(iteration, res.data.market_data.current_price.usd)
                setCoinData(iteration, res.data.market_data.current_price.usd)
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
      
        iteration--
    }
```

the console log returns this `9 : 1 42274.907370256085`

```
instead of:
 9 42274.907370256085
 8 42274.907370256085
 7 42274.907370256085
etc:
```

Comment: Async behavior. By the time the first request returns, your `iteration` variable has already reached 0.

Comment: Is there any way around it?

Comment: The "console" in many browsers, simply does not show repeated same output. There will be a "instance count" of that same output. But this likely doesn't apply here since its an ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

As **Robby Cornelissen** stated, .then().catch() is asynchronous.

Asynchronous behaviour is basically like when you run some code, but don't wait for it to finish before you run the code below it.

You can read more up about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_async.asp

One solution would be to use try/catch await.

```
iteration = 10
while (iteration != 1) {
  try{
    await axios.get(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/history?date=11-04-2022`)

    console.log(iteration, res.data.market_data.current_price.usd)
    setCoinData(iteration, res.data.market_data.current_price.usd)
  }catch(err){
      console.log(err)
  }
  
    iteration--
}
```

Keep in mind that I am trying to help from a mobile device, so I am unable to test this and the code formatting might be a bit wonk.